# Calender in inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show datepicker in input box.4 days before This code show datepicker.Now I modified unknownly.I dont know What I changed.Here I attached my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jscodes.com/codes/calendar_javascript/demo/css/datePicker.css" />
    <script src="http://www.jscodes.com/codes/calendar_javascript/demo/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jscodes.com/codes/calendar_javascript/demo/js/jquery.datePicker-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Content Delv Logs</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).ready(function() {
            $('#date-pick').datePicker({clickInput: true});
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <input type="text" name="date" id="date-pick" value=""/>
</body>
```

Comment: you may have forgotten jQuery UI- http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/D4AGz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

use jquery UI with alot of functions and more to give;;;

> http://jqueryui.com/
>
> http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 2):

Add this link in your head tag. You are missing jQuery UI library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable jQuery UI.

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cta37m5x/)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Please note how jQueryUI is enabled.